# How to read/extract lines with more than 20 spaces ? - unix/python

Tags: python, unix, if-statement, text-files, yield

The required task is to extract lines that contains x number of occurence of y. The input text file contains 1,000,000 lines of 50-200 characters per line.

In this case, let's say lines that contains 20 whitespaces. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? Currently, I'm doing it this way:

```
import codecs

def readlinesmorethan20spaces(intxtfile):
    with codecs.open(intxtfile, 'r','utf8') as fin:
        for i in fin:
            if i.count(" ") > 20:
                yield i.strip()

for i in readlinesmorethan20spaces("in.txt"):
    print i
```

How can this be done without python but with unix commands? Is it even possible?

Comment: Wait, do you want something more pythonic, or a unix version?

Comment: Do you mean ` ` or `\s`?. There is a difference between "space" and "whitespace"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix way using grep and sed:

```
grep -E '(\s[^\s]*){20,}' in.txt | sed 's/^\s*//;s/\s*$//'
```

The first command filters lines with 20+ whitespaces (even non consecutive), the second command then strips leading and trailing whitespaces.

This isn’t an ideal approach, it’s probably slower then others (awk maybe), but it’s quite simple. By the way, I’d be interested in performance comparison of different methods mentioned on this page…

*Yeah, almost everything can be solved with regular expressions! ;)*

Answer (score 0):

List comps are just generally more pythonic. In your context it would look something like this:

```
import codecs, re

def readlinesmorethan20spaces(intxtfile):
    with codecs.open(intxtfile, 'r','utf8') as fin:
        return (i.strip() for i in fin if i.count(' ') > 20)

for i in readlinesmorethan20spaces("in.txt"):
    print i
```

In that context, returning a generator is similarly lazy to your previous `yield` statement.

You could also do it as a single line if you want, though I think the above version is more readable:

```
read_lines = lambda fn: (i.strip() for i in codecs.open(fn, 'r', 'utf8') if i.count(' ') > 20)
```

The unix approach is less straightforward, but this should totally be possible. The start is probably to use `awk` to count the characters in each line. Here's an example:

```
awk -v FS=""'{cnt=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==" ") cnt++; print cnt"\t"NR}' stores.dat
```

Comment: That would be for 20 consecutive spaces. I expect regex to be slower for this anyway.

Comment: @gnibbler I totally misread the question, thanks for that. Not using regex wins again!

Comment: Your first answer won't work. The file is closed before the generator expression reads from it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually not bother with a generator

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(intxtfile, 'r','utf8') as fin:
    for i in fin:
        if i.count(' ') <= 20:
            continue
        i = i.strip()
        ...
```

One advantage of using a function/generator would be finer grained components to unittest. As mentioned in the comments - moving things around a little makes the generator much easier to test as `fin` doesn't need to be a open file - it could equally well be a list etc.

```
import codecs

def readlinesmorethan20spaces(fin):
    for i in fin:
        if i.count(" ") > 20:
            yield i.strip()

with codecs.open(intxtfile, 'r','utf8') as fin:
    for i in readlinesmorethan20spaces(fin):
        print i
```

Comment: if it faster/more pythonic to check for non-conditions than conditions?

Comment: Not sure exactly the context, but reading in 1,000,000 lines might well be slow enough that a generator really does make sense in this context.

Comment: @Slater, A generator still needs to read the file a line at a time. You'll probably see a little extra overhead jumping back and forth from the generator. Anyone care to time it?

Comment: @gnibbler yes, but it doesn't have to do it all at once. Simply generating everything will be slower than a list, but there are many contexts in which lazy evaluation is crucial.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus, This loop is lazy (doesn't read the whole file at once). Why do you think it's not?

Comment: @gnibbler it's neither at present, but saying to not bother with a generator implied that you didn't think the lazy evaluation was necessary/useful. More talking about that comment than the code.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus, A generator may be more appropriate for more complicated filtering. For testability sake it's better to pass in an iterable instead of a filename. Otherwise the unit test is forced to create temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

Other way with high-performance container [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import codecs
import collections

def readlinesmorethan20spaces(intxtfile):
    with codecs.open(intxtfile, 'r','utf8') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            counter = collections.Counter(line)
            if counter[" "] > 20:
                yield line.strip()

for i in readlinesmorethan20spaces("in.txt"):
    print i
```

Comment: No. Counter will be really slow for this. Try it if you don't believe me